# Delete a Node in C

Tags: c, binary-search

I have a problem trying to delete a node in a BST. Whenever I run my main class, it tries to print Inorder traversal but crashes after the 1st node. Here is my deletion code: (Note: I am using C)

```
bst bst_delete(bst b, char *str){
  /*Deleting a key which doesn't exist in the tree should have no effect. (Base Case) */
  if(b == NULL) return b;
  /*If the key to be deleted is smaller than the root(b)'s key, then it lies in the left subtree */
  if( strcmp(str, b->key) < 0){
    bst_delete(b->left, str);
  /*If the key to be deleted is greater than the root(b)'s key, then it lies in the right subtree */
  }else if ( strcmp(str, b->key) > 0){
    bst_delete(b->right, str);
  /*If the key is the same as the root(b)'s key, then THIS is the node to be deleted */
  }else{
    /*Case where node has no children*/
    if(b->left == NULL && b->right == NULL){
      free(b->key);
      bst_free(b);
      b = NULL;
      /*Case where there is a child in the right subtree*/
    }else if(b->left == NULL){
      bst temp = b;
      b = b->right;
      bst_delete(temp, str);
      /*Case where there is a child in the left subtree*/
    }else if(b->right == NULL){
       bst temp = b;
      b = b->left;
      bst_delete(temp, str);
      /*Case where there are 2 children*/
    }else{
      bst temp = bst_minValueNode(b->right); /*Find the leftmost (smallest) child of the left subtree (the successor).*/
      b->key = temp->key; /*Swap the node's key with the sucessor's key.*/
      b->right = bst_delete(b->right, temp->key); /*Delete the key from the right subtree.*/
    }
  }
  return b;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a *debugger*.

Comment: Hi, my code compiles, but the output is wrong.

Comment: Code that compiles means little in terms of its correctness. *Whenever I run my main class* ... *Note: I am using C*. This is already confusing. C doesn't have classes. Exactly what are you running? How are you calling `bst_delete`? How is your tree created? All of these things could affect your problem. What do you mean by "crashes"? It looks like you are assuming the problem is inside of `bst_delete` but you haven't explained what you've done to debug and what has led you to this conclusion.

Comment: Please make up your mind, does it crash or produce the wrong output? Perhaps you should take some time to *also* [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). However, the way to fix both problems (crashes or wrong output) is *still* to use a debugger.

Comment: Sorry that is my bad, I meant to say that my program compiles correctly, but the output is not desired. I can also provide the rest of the code and the main method.

Comment: Do not provide all of the code. Just the code that is essential to the problem. You also need to learn to use the debugger. It will show you where the crash is occurring if it's an invalid memory access (although you haven't yet said what "crash" means). That would narrow the problem down considerably.

Comment: We want all relevant code ("C"), but nothing else ("M"), we want all the needed side code ("V") and we want the code to reproduce the problem ("E"). So please make a "MCVE", [mcve].

Comment: Are keys unique in your tree? Why is it that in your `else` leg, where you've established that the key matches the current node, that you are doing ` bst_delete(temp, str);` on the left or right legs with the key you wish to delete?

Comment: Yes, all my keys are unique, and to answer your 2nd question: if you delete the node that has 2 children or 1 child, you need to reset the pointers in the bst.

Comment: ..and, of course, you are absolutely sure that your BST is valid?

Comment: ..because if not, your question, 'I have a problem trying to delete a node in a BST' is also invalid.

Comment: @Makasulee I don't understand why you're trying to delete the key from the left or right leg when you've already deleted the current node what was determined to match the key.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the problem but i can see two problems with your code at a glance.

1) The code snippet(and similar code) -

```
if( strcmp(str, b->key) < 0){
    bst_delete(b->left, str);
  /*If the key to be deleted is greater than the root(b)'s key, then it lies in the right subtree */
  }
```

You might want to change this to -

```
if( strcmp(str, b->key) < 0){
    b->left=bst_delete(b->left, str);
  /*If the key to be deleted is greater than the root(b)'s key, then it lies in the right subtree */
  }
```

Although, it is least likely to give the error as you are dealing with pointers but still....

2) Code snippet(and similar codes) -

```
else if(b->left == NULL){
      bst temp = b;
      b = b->right;
      bst_delete(temp, str);
      /*Case where there is a child in the left subtree*/
    }
```

In this case, you need to make the right child of `temp` **NULL**. As otherwise it is just going to keep making recursive calls and cause segmentation fault.

So modifing it to following code may help -

```
else if(b->left == NULL){
      bst temp = b;
      b = b->right;
      temp->right=NULL;
      bst_delete(temp, str);
      /*Case where there is a child in the left subtree*/
    }
```